# Comparing Rate of Convergence of Two Square Root Algorithms

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence

**Source**: Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" 3.17(d)

**Problem**: Compare the rapidity of convergence of the process

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha+x_n}{1+x_n}=x_n+\frac{\alpha-x_n^2}{1+x_n}$$
with $\alpha>1$ and $x_1>\sqrt{\alpha}$ with the process
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{\alpha}{x_n}\right).$$
In 16b, Rudin lets $\epsilon_n = x_n-\sqrt{\alpha}$ and we show that with $\beta=2\sqrt{\alpha}$,
$$\epsilon_{n+1}<\beta\left(\frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta}\right)^{2^n}.$$

**My work**:
For finding the rate of convergence in 16, we must find the $$\alpha\geq 1: \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|\epsilon_{n+1}|}{|\epsilon_n|^\alpha}<\infty.$$ After 16b, we can deduce that with $\alpha=2$, the limit converges and so the rate of convergence is quadratic. For the latter, we just go through the same process as in 16b,c. I think $\beta=\frac{(\sqrt{\alpha}-1)x_1-1+\sqrt{\alpha})}{2x_1+1+\alpha}$ gives us a similar inequality as in 16b. Then from here,
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|\beta\left(\frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta}\right)^n\right|}{\left|\beta\left(\frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta}\right)^{n-1}\right|^\alpha}<\infty\iff \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}n-(n-1)\alpha<\infty\iff \alpha=1.$$
Hence it's rate of convergence is linear at best.

**My Question**: I was hoping to get some feedback on if my work is sufficient/good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one,

$\begin{array}\\
x_{n+1}
&=\dfrac{a+x_n}{1+x_n}\\
\text{so}\\
x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}
&=\dfrac{a+x_n}{1+x_n}-\sqrt{a}\\
&=\dfrac{a+x_n-\sqrt{a}(1+x_n)}{1+x_n}\\
&=\dfrac{a+x_n-\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a}x_n}{1+x_n}\\
&=\dfrac{a-\sqrt{a}+x_n-\sqrt{a}x_n}{1+x_n}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{a}-1)-x_n(\sqrt{a}-1)}{1+x_n}\\
&=\dfrac{(\sqrt{a}-1)(\sqrt{a}-x_n)}{1+x_n}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}-x_n}
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}-1}{1+x_n}\\
\text{or}\\
\dfrac{x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}}{x_n-\sqrt{a}}
&=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{a}}{1+x_n}\\
\end{array}
$

so the convergence is linear.

For Newton,

$\begin{array}\\
x_{n+1}
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\dfrac{a}{x_n}\right)\\
\text{so}\\
x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\dfrac{a}{x_n}\right)-\sqrt{a}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x_n-2\sqrt{a}+\dfrac{a}{x_n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x_n^2-2x_n\sqrt{a}+a}{x_n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{(x_n-\sqrt{a})^2}{x_n}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

so the convergence is quadratic.